# Can not find source map

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, npm-install, zegocloud

[image]

I has this warning since I install zego-ui-toolkit. I trying reinstall and also delete node_modules but not working. This is not an error that cause my system fail but it really annoying.

Comment: What version are you using of zego-ui-toolkit? Seems you are a pre build could you use the latest stable build instead?

Might also be that it is not compatible with the NodeJs or react version you are using since its a prebuild and probably not fully tested on all node versions.

Comment: @starking I'm asking the zego admin but they not reply yet. It's been 3 days

Answer (score 1):

```
const { override, useBabelRc } = require('customize-cra');
const ignoreWarnings = (value) => (config) => {
    config.ignoreWarnings = value;
    return config;
};

module.exports = override(useBabelRc(), ignoreWarnings([/Failed to parse source map/]));
```

I added in my config-override.js and the warning gone. But I want only the warning from zego-ui-toolkit  is ignore. What can I do.

Answer (score 0):

I know that feel. If you're using webpack, you can configure you `webpack.config.js` to ignore this specific warning.

```
plugins: [
  /* Your code */
  new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/flv\.js\.map$/, /zego-ui-kit-prebuilt/),
],
```

More information you can read about `IgnorePlugin` is here:
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/

As you mentioned, it won't affect your application work, but it will affect debugging, cause you will see minified code instead of initial(original) source code in developer tools. I believe, that's all.

Comment: I don't have webpack.config.js  bro :(. Is there anyway this disable it? @piskunovim

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try an earlier version.

You can find more version here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zegocloud/zego-uikit-prebuilt/v/1.7.4?activeTab=versions

Its bad to ignore faults/warnings if you don´t know for sure they are harmless. Might also come new warnings that you want to see.

Comment: I already updated to newest version of zegoCloud, but the warning still appear.

Comment: I mean that you can test older versions of the libs. Like a version 3 months ago `npm i @zegocloud/zego-uikit-prebuilt@1.6.2` if that works you can try a newer version until you it stops working. If its not working try even older version.